# How to solve NSURLErrorDomain: Cannot decode raw data in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, gzip, objectmapper

I am trying to send request to server. I get status code as 200, content-length is 90956 and result return

```
FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1015 "cannot decode raw data" in swift 4
```

I tried to change parameter encoding value as `JSONEncoding.Default` but nothing happen.

```
AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params, headers:headers)
        .responseString { response in
            print("Request :- " , response.request as Any)
            print("Response error :- ", response.error as Any)
            print("Response :- ", response.response as Any)
    }
```

Actual

```
Data None
Network Duration: 0.06679093837738037s Duration: 2.5987625122070312e-05s
Result: FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1015 "cannot decode raw data"
```

Expected

```
Data: 90956 Network Duration: 0.06679093837738037s Duration: 2.5987625122070312e-05s Result: SUCCESS
```

Comment: What is the received data supposed to be? The error implies it's not a string.

Comment: Don't use `.responseString{}`, but `response{}`, print the `response.value` as NSData.

Comment: Sir, the response will be gzip compressed data. and response{} is not working with it

Comment: [Result]: FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1015 "cannot decode raw data" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=cannot decode raw data. This return me back. I need result as successful

Comment: Is the error about unzipping or data can't be parsed into a String? For instance, if it's an image, that could be why. So can you retrieve the raw data? At least, do it with a URLSession, or curl.

Comment: In android application, the data is in encrypted format and is gzipd. We intercept the response and decompress the data using GZIPInputStream, then we get encrypted string from response, we decrypt it and stored in Classes and object. Something like this :- 'TypeToken<UserLocationListEntity> token = new TypeToken<UserLocationListEntity>() {};
                        UserLocationListEntity response = getParser().fromJson(decryptedData, token.getType());' Here decryptedData is in string format.

Comment: If it's *gzip compressed data* then it can't be a string so the parameter `.responseString` is wrong. That's what the error says. If it's raw data use `.responseData`

Comment: Request GET http://192.168.2.3/PreProdApi/Authentication/UserAccessDataGet?Username=deo%40solarig.com
Status Code: 200
Content-Length: 90956
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 24 May 2019 09:29:11 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Data: None
[Result]: FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1015 "cannot decode raw data" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=cannot decode raw data, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.2.3/PreProdApi/Authentication/UserAccessDataGet?Username=deo%40solarig.com, This is response i get from Server. Please help me

Comment: Can you use `.responseData{}` instead of `.responseString`? And what's the output then of the rawData? Still the same?

Comment: yes the error is same

Comment: Can you make your request work with POSTMAN? curl in Terminal.app?

Comment: I am using Alamofire as a networking library. Request url data should be gzipped and response from server is gzipped data. How i unzip it. and map in my object and classes in swift

Comment: Please someone help me out from getting out of this issue.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?